# Only follows second parameter

Tags: google-apps-script

in the following code script for google Spreadsheets, I tried to make a program in which two pieces of information would be inputted to return a desired value that depends on BOTH values. Say, getValcharge ("OptionA", 2000) would return "76", or getValcharge ("OptionB",6000) would return 70. However, it seems to me that I keep getting returned the very last value possible: getValcharge("OptionA"/"OptionB"/"OptionC",1000) would return me "30". Even if I were to put an "OptionD" for the value, it would return "30" if the second number is under 5001.

Thus, it seems to only follow the second parameter --and thus only the second--even when closed off and is supposed to be not accessible to the first.

I am new to Script editor but do have modest Java experience (it'd work were this Java..) Could someone offer any advice/fixes? Any is appreciated. Thanks.

```
function getValcharge (valType, valAmount) {

var valcost =0;

if(valType="OptionA"){

       if(valAmount < 5001)
            {valcost = 76;} 

      if(valAmount > 5000 && valAmount <10001)
            {valcost = 113;}

}

  if(valType="OptionB"){

        if(valAmount < 5001)
          {valcost=43; }

        if(valAmount > 5000 && valAmount <10001)
          {valcost = 70;}
  }

 if(valType="OptionC")
{

         if(valAmount < 5001)
            { valcost = 30; } 
         if(valAmount > 5000 && valAmount <10001)
            { valcost = 46; }
}

return valcost; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript you need to use a double-equals sign to test for equivalence, eg:

```
if(valType=="OptionA"){
```